# How do I incoporate gyro information in my position and velocity calculation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

The velocity in 1 direction can be calculated as :

$V_t=V_0+at$

And position could be calculated as

$P_t=V_0t+1/2at^2$.

Besides time, acceleration, I was also given information from 3 axis gyroscope. Unfortunately, I have no idea about the unit (I think they should be in degree/second?)

[image]

Having said that, do you think the position formula will change if I incoporate the information from 3axis gyroscope?

---

Also, it would be helpful if you can help to calculate the position in Quaternion form using these information.

Comment: I would suggest that you learn the proper math do describe the motions of rigid objects, then you take a deep breath and decide if you really want to do this, it's non-trivial and if you hope to make any sense of your portable device sensor data with it, think again, it's far harder than you imagine right now.

Comment: Quaternion form?

Comment: @KyleKanos - yes, quaternion. A common way to describe rotation in computer graphics etc - has some nice properties. [See link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)

Comment: @floris: I know what a quaternion is, but I've never seen it used to do 3d kinematics (or more specifically, rigid body dynamics queried here) and am questioning that.

Comment: @KyleKanos OK I understand your comment now. I suppose the position, orientation and rotation of the object can all be described as quaternions (plus one distance) but it is a bit unusual. Not sure if it would make the math simpler or harder. Never tried it.

Answer (score 1):

What data do you have for linear motion?  Your equations are correct if you have the acceleration as a function of time and the orientation is constant.  The angular accelerometer can give you the angles as a function of time with integration.  Unfortunately, drift can be a problem.  The received wisdom is to use an accelerometer (linear or angle), integrate it for velocity, again for position, and to update based on a position sensor (magnetometer for angles?) to take care of drift.  Note that integration emphasizes low frequency errors like drift.